# How to apply setItemChecked(position,true) with RecyclerView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am developing a Material Design Navigation Drawer. I've created a new class `RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` in it to handle the user's click on the list items. I use the class this way within the `MainActivity` class' `onCreate` method:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {// do whatever
                    if(position!=0){
                        setItemChecked(position, true);
                        setSelectable(true);
                        boolean isSelected = view.isSelected();
                        view.setActivated(isSelected);

                        selectItem(position);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position){
                    // ...
                }
            })
    );
```

I based this code from this blog post: [RecyclerView part 2](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/)  but it's not getting the job done, and to me it's not clear at all on how am I supposed to get it working. 
I've also checked out this seemingly easy solution: [Innodroid - Tracking Selected Item in RecyclerView](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/tracking-selected-item-in-recyclerview) (also quoted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838834/2395491)) but it's not clear on how I am supposed to derive my `MyAdapter` class to the `TrackSelectionAdapter` class.

What's the best way to highlight list items? I'm stuck.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, I've found the best tutorial on how to use the RecyclerView with all functions we need and with no libraries (single+multiselection, hightlight, ripple, click and remove in multiselection, etc...). From a first look it seems well explained.

Here it is --> http://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/

**[EDIT]** I finally found the time to try it out and I even created my own more flexible, everybody can benefit my **improvements**: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter.
In this link I also explain how it works. Please have a look and feel free to add it to your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for this tutorial, it helped me a lot! I've implemented the `MyAdapter` class and then extended the `CickListener` interface with the 2 methods `onItemClick` and `onItemLongClick` and worked like a charm!