# Android - selectable recyclerview item with selectable views in it

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview, android-recyclerview

I have got a `RecyclerView` item looking like this[image: item]

I want to achieve that when I click on item the `ImageView` will get overlay over it and `TextView` will become bold. I know how to use adapter and where to handle item clicks. I also know how to make overlay or bold text. I only want to know how to make this item selectable to get the behavior I described above. Because I found only tutorials to change background of item when clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight selected item inside a RecyclerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390682/highlight-selected-item-inside-a-recyclerview)

Comment: just add click listener on each item's of your RecyclerView that you need and make them clickable in xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this

> I only want to know how to make this item selectable to get the behavior I described above.

So basically you need a way to tell the ViewHolder that the current item is selected, such that in `onBindViewHolder()` the items are rendered as per need.

I can think of this: Make a model of the item youre adding to the RecyclerView. Add a key as `boolean isSelected = false` in it.

And inside your `onBindViewHolder` where youre implementing the `onClick()`interface. do this:

```
... new OnClickListener({
    ... onClick(){
        // take the item and set the isSelected flag
        list.get(position).setIsSelected(true):
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // alternatively you can also toggle this flag. 
    }
});
```

and while loading inside `onBindViewHolder` to this:

```
if (list.get(position).isSelected()) {
    // highlight aka set overlay and bold text to view
} else {
    // as per recyclerview doc, reset the views. 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. ´boolean isSelected´ is probably what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is having a variable to hold the selected index. Then decorating the selected item in onBindViewHolder() method.

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
...
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (selectedIndex == position) {
        // Do things you want
    }
}
```