# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int $ViewHolder.getPosition()' on a null object reference in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to change the color of the view when it's selected in RecyclerView.
I used the adapter from this tutorial: http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html and add the onClick method from the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868923/3569225.
This is my code now:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
    // IF the view under inflation and population is header or Item
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
    private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java

    private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name

    private int mSelectedPosition = 0;
    private OnMyListItemClick mOnMainMenuClickListener = OnMyListItemClick.NULL;

    // Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
    // ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        int Holderid;

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView Name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
            super(itemView);
            // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

            if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
                Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
            }
            else{
                Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
                Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
            }
        }
    }

    public interface OnMyListItemClick {
        OnMyListItemClick NULL = new OnMyListItemClick() {
            @Override
            public void onMyListItemClick(View itemView) {

            }
        };

        void onMyListItemClick(View itemView);
    }

    MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name){ // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
        // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
        mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
        mIcons = Icons;
        name = Name;
        //in adapter
    }



    //Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
    //Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
    // if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
    // and pass it to the view holder

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            final ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //here you set your current position from holder of clicked view
                    mSelectedPosition = ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).getPosition();

                    //here you pass object from your list - item value which you clicked
                    //OnMainMenuClickListener.onMyListItemClick(yourObjectList.get(mSelectedPosition));

                    //here you inform view that something was change - view will be invalidated
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return vhItem; // Returning the created object
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            return vhHeader; //returning the object created
        }

        return null;

    }

    //Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
    // Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
    // which view type is being created 1 for item row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
            // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
            holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons

            if(mSelectedPosition == position)
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            else
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else{
            holder.Name.setText(name);
        }
    }

    // you can create your own listener which you set for adapter
    public void setOnMainMenuClickListener(OnMyListItemClick onMyListItemClick) {
        mOnMainMenuClickListener = onMyListItemClick == null ? OnMyListItemClick.NULL : onMyListItemClick;
    }
    // This method returns the number of items present in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
    }


    // Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

}
```

But when I am clicking item, the app is crash and the error is :`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.*****.******.app.MyAdapter$ViewHolder.getPosition()' on a null object reference`.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Call the onClick on the bind method instead. By calling `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener` instead.

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira thanks, I was need to change the getPosition to the position int in the bind method and now it's working, thanks :)

Comment: If you want to get the holder for a certain view you have to call `RecyclerView.getChildViewHolder`