# how to change the text color of selected item inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items using recycler view. I need to change the text color (textview color) of item when it is selected to indicate that the particular item is selected. Below is my adapter code. Kindly suggest me how to achieve this.

```
@Override
public GridView_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_customview, viewGroup, false);

    gridHolder = new GridView_Holder(itemView);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawableSelected = new ColorDrawable(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.borderColor));
    // create StateListDrawable object and define its states
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, colorDrawableSelected);
    stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, null);
    // set the StateListDrawable as background of the item view
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        itemView.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
    }
    else {
        itemView.setBackground(stateListDrawable);
    }

    return  new GridView_Holder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GridView_Holder holder, int position) {

    model = arrayList.get(position);
    gridHolder = (GridView_Holder) holder;// Holder
    gridHolder.tvTitle.setText(model.getVideoName());    //set title                        

    Glide.with(context).load(model.getVideoImageThumbnail())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(gridHolder.imageView);
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            GridLayoutManager lm = ((GridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)
                {
                    if(mCurrentSelectedPosition + 6 < getItemCount())
                    {
                        gridHolder = (GridView_Holder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
                        gridHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                        notifyItemChanged(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
                        int lastItem = lm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                        if((mCurrentSelectedPosition+6) > lastItem)
                        {
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition+6);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gridHolder = (GridView_Holder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition+6);
                            gridHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                        }

                        mCurrentSelectedPosition += 6 ;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) 
                {
                }

                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
                    if(mCurrentSelectedPosition + 1 < getItemCount())
                    {
                        gridHolder = (GridView_Holder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
                        gridHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                        notifyItemChanged(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
                        int lastItem = lm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                        if((mCurrentSelectedPosition+1) > lastItem)
                        {
                                                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition+1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gridHolder = (GridView_Holder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(mCurrentSelectedPosition+1);
                            gridHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                        }
                        mCurrentSelectedPosition += 1 ;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly highlight selected item on RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194044/how-to-properly-highlight-selected-item-on-recyclerview)

Comment: @0X0nosugar I want to change the text color. don't want to make it high lighted.

Comment: Please look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35360331/5015207) to the linked question. The only difference is the other OP wanted to highlight something (`setBackgroundColor()`) whereas you want to change the text color (`setTextColor()`).

Comment: setTextColor() gives error when I call it like this. holder.itemview.setTextColor()

Comment: holder.itemview seems to be a View, so no text. But maybe you want to change the color of something like gridHolder.tvTitle ?

Comment: yeah but how call the gridHolder.tvTitle of selected position.

Answer (score 0):

In your GridView_Holder class:

```
public final TextView textView,

    public GridView_Holder(View itemView, int type) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            }

         @Override
            public void onItemSelected() {
               textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.accent));
            }

        @Override
            public void onItemClear() {
              textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
            }
```