# Change clicked button's color on a recycler view containing buttons in each row

Tags: android, arraylist, dynamic, android-recyclerview, background-color

I added some Button in RecyclerView, The button are dynamically added ,based on the size of the list. Now button added successfully based on the list, where I need help is, when i click a button, the button should be hightlighted. And when  i click another button, then the previously clicked button should get back default color and newly clicked button should be highlighted.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Pls paste some code so we can understand what u have tried so far

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30046476/5425930

Comment: codes are in my office pc , so i unable to paste it right now.

Comment: i tried to change the background color of the button when i click, it work , but when i click another button , that button also change back ground, but i want that the already choosen button get back to the default color.

Comment: i exactly want that , sub headers  in stackoverflow editor(questions, jobs, documentation,.....). when i click Question tab, it change in to orange color, after that i click the jobs tab , it change in to orange color , but the previously clicked question tab get back in to default gray color.. pls help to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

When adding button set id of button to the position of listitem

In your adapater for RecyclerView add a variable :

```
private int selectedItem = -1;
```

on ClickOfButton set the selectedItem to button position .And then in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int i) {
    // Set selected state; use a state list drawable to style the view
   if(selectedItem == i)
       viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(i).setBackground(..);
    }else{
     viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(i).setBackground(..);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Its not working for me.. the lastly generated button only highlighted, but i'm not click on that button.

Comment: if(mSelecteditem == position){

            holder.header_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cb_orange);
        }else {
            holder.header_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cb_blue);

        }

Comment: i exactly want that , sub headers in stackoverflow editor(questions, jobs, documentation,.....). when i click Question tab, it change in to orange color, after that i click the jobs tab , it change in to orange color , but the previously clicked question tab get back in to default gray color.. pls help to achieve this..

Comment: Can you add the code where you dynamically add the button , and set the adapter .

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter add a variable:

```
private int previousSeletedButtonId = 0;
```

then just check inside `onBindViewHolder` on Button Click

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int currentlySelectedButton) {

        viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(currentlySelectedButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        if(previousSeletedButtonId == currentlySelectedButton){
               viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(previousSeletedButtonId).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.orange));
        }
        else{
            viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(previousSeletedButtonId).setBackgroundColor(grey);
            viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(currentlySelectedButton).setBackgroundColor(orange);
            }
        }
      });
     }
```

May this help you.
Remember don't forget the to save id of button on click in else part.

```
currentlySelectedButton = previousSeletedButtonId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to put the code in the OnClick inside ViewHolder, but it should work everywhere. Using **previousSeletedButton** you has every time access to the previously selected button:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public Button aButton;
    public static Button previousSeletedButton = null;
    private Context context;
```

.....

```
// Handles the row being clicked
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

        if ( ( previousSeletedButton == null ) || ( previousSeletedButton == this.aButton ) ) {
            this.aButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor( context, R.color.orange) );
        }
        else{
            previousSeletedButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor( context, R.color.grey) );
            this.aButton.setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor( context, R.color.orange) );
        }
        previousSeletedButton = this.aButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me everytime

```
class PageNumberAdapter(private val onItemClick: (PageNumber) -> Unit) : ListAdapter<PageNumber, PageNumberAdapter.PageNumberViewHolder>(NumberDiffCallback) {

 var currentSelection = 0

inner class PageNumberViewHolder(val binding: NumbersListRvItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(pageNumber: PageNumber) {
            with(binding) {
                pageNumberTv.text = pageNumber.pageNum.toString()
                // change background color onclick
                val backgroundResource: Int =
                    if (currentSelection == absoluteAdapterPosition) R.drawable.color_gradient
                    else R.drawable.signup_btn_bg
              
                PageNumberItemLayout.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource)

              root.setOnClickListener {
                    if (absoluteAdapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return@setOnClickListener
                    currentSelection = absoluteAdapterPosition
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                    onItemClick.invoke(pageNumber)
                }
```