# RecyclerView - highlight selected item after inserting value in SQL

Tags: android, sql, android-recyclerview

I made SQL database and manage to populate RecyclerView with inserted data. For the next part of the project, I need to highlight selected item (changeBackgroundColor etc) in RecyclerView, after I inserted a value for that chosen item.

onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Food singleFood = foodList.get(position);

    holder.foodName.setText(singleFood.getName());
    holder.enterGram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editTaskDialog(singleFood);
        }
    });
}
```

In `editTaskDialog()` method I called AlertDialog with one EditText widget and `setPositiveButton()`, `setNegativeButton()`.
So after the user choose one item from RecyclerView and enters the value in that EditText and touches `setPositiveButton()`, that selected item must be highlighted, because in next activity I need to operate with that selected items and entered values. `setPositiveButton()` will call update method and save that value in SQL database (that part is done).

I understand that I need to check selected item with a row in SQL database (entered value). In case that they match or equal I need to call `setBackgroundColor()` or some similar method. I'm just not sure how to do that correctly.

After that, I hope I will somehow figure out how to manipulate with these selected items. But that is not part of this question.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Let me know if u are interested in some more code, to better understand my question.

Comment: have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28838834/7290822

Comment: I understand that. But how to do it outside of onBindViewHolder() method ?

Comment: any specific reason why do you want to do that