# RecyclerView Adapter highlight clicked or current item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

As I'm new to android, I'm struggling to highlight Recyclerview clicked or current item. I have tried some workarounds but nothing helps. Basically I want to highlight selected item even after it is coming back from respective Fragment. Please check my code and help me to get done. Thanks.

```
public class ContentaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentaAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<String> ItemTitle;
    ArrayList<String> ItemSource;

    public ContentaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> ItemTitle, ArrayList<String> ItemSource) {
        this.context = context;
        this.ItemTitle = ItemTitle;
        this.ItemSource = ItemSource;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_items_layout, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.ItemTitle.setText(ItemTitle.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Fragment contentdisplay = new ViewContentFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("ItemTitle",ItemTitle);
                bundle.putStringArrayList("ItemSource",ItemSource);
                bundle.putInt("position",position);
                bundle.putInt("ItemCounts",ItemTitle.size());
                contentdisplay.setArguments(bundle);
                ((MainActivity)context).replaceFragment(contentdisplay);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ItemTitle.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView ItemTitle;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ItemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, don't call "replaceFragment" from the Adapter and don't do Android API calls at all from the Adapter, use Listener (Interface) which to pass this event (onItemClick) into the Activity

Comment: And maybe you can find something helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194044/how-to-properly-highlight-selected-item-on-recyclerview or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will give a Try !!

Answer (score 0):

you need to to add `isSelected` state in to your list item data model and change it `onClick`.

And when you know state you can change background in `ViewHolder`

```
 if (isSelected) {
            //  set selected background here
        } else {
            //  set not selected background here
        }
```

And instead of keeping two lists in adapter you should create one with model `ArrayList<DataModel>` similar to this:

```
class DataModel {
    String ItemTitle;
    String ItemSource;
    Boolean isSelected;
}
```

also you shouldn't pass both list to other fragment, instead take only what you need, for example `yourList.get(position);`

Comment: Thanks for your info. can you please explain me bit more?

Comment: see updated answer, isSelected would be your background state boolean