# Cannot highlight items in RecyclerView with selectors

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I want simply highlight item when I press on it.

I have selectors below (@drawable/expandable_menu)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
<item android:drawable="@color/purple_200" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/purple_500" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/chat" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

In my onclick listener I select this item

RecyclerView XML:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat_messages"
        app:stackFromEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/expandable_menu"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:focusable="true">
```

Message XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="left"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_msg_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="this is me"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I followed this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30046476) but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set `OnClickListener` to `View`, which have selector set as background. I see you have selector set for `TextView` (child), are you setting onClick to this `View` or for whole `itemView` (which in your case is root `RelativeLayout`)?

you may also try to add `android:duplicateParentState` for `TextView` - this should make `TextView` draw pressed state when parent is pressed, not only `TextView` itself (which isn't clickable at all when no `OnClickListener` set)

Comment: I set selected state and onClickListener to holder.itemView element